# When should I use Rest or SOAP web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I know this has been debated already, but in my opinion I could't figure out the answer.

I would always use SOAP, why complicate?

Answer (score 1):

REST is good if you know you are dealing with HTTP only.

SOAP is good if you are using protocols other than HTTP(S). SOAP for example can be used to communicate with a service over email.